# How to improve JSON response time in phonegap

Tags: jquery, json, cordova, phonegap-plugins, phonegap-build

I'm Building mobile application using phonegap with server/Database connectivity !
I connected my application to database through PHP & MYSQL with JSON reply.

but it's very slow for reading data from server

Help me to solve this problem

My configurations are

- I'm using Godaddy Deluxe Package (Shared Hosting)
- Language : PHP & MySQL
- Data Format : JSON & JSONP

Comment: You need to provide a lot more information to expect any reasonable answer to your question.

Comment: That's right; you'll need to provide a bit more information in order to get an accurate answer. What are you requesting from the server? How often? How much data is being returned? How long is the request taking? How long is it taking to render?

Answer (score 1):

Your question is a bit broad, but there are a few ideas I can suggest.

1) Look at how much time it takes for your PHP to generate JSON. It could be slow due to your query. That could mean you need to improve your indexing in MySQL, or perhaps improve your PHP code. Basically - find out how many seconds it takes from requesting foo.php to getting a result.

2) Look at the size of your JSON. If you are returning 100,000 rows, that's a lot of data. You would want to limit (or paginate) your data, and consider removing data you don't need. For example, imagine your query returns all the columns from the db, but your front end code only uses two of them. I'd then modify the query to only return those two columns.